# When I have layered backgrounds, how can I create padding around content?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a child theme for the Hatch theme. 
I'd like to have a fixed image in the background, and a white background that spans 90% of the width and scrolls with the body.

Problem: I can't get padding around the body of the text (it runs all the way to the edge)

Here is a link to the site: http://www.westonsnorwood.com

and here is the text I tried in my style.css sheet:

```
    /*
Theme Name: hatch-child
Theme URL: http://www.westonsnorwood.com
Description: Hatch Child Theme
Author: Weston Norwood
Template: hatch
*/
@import url('../hatch/style.css');

body{
 margin: 0 10;
 padding: 10px;
 }

.wrap {
 background: #f6f6f6;
 background-position: center center; 
 max-width: 80%;
 padding: 20;
}

body{
 background-image: url(http://www.westonsnorwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/woodgrainlight.jpg);
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is the way you wrote your `.wrap` padding style. It wasn't told what to do with that "20", so what you want to do is turn it into `20px`.

**Final code:**

```
    /*
Theme Name: hatch-child
Theme URL: http://www.westonsnorwood.com
Description: Hatch Child Theme
Author: Weston Norwood
Template: hatch
*/
@import url('../hatch/style.css');

body{
 margin: 0 10;
 padding: 10px;
 }

.wrap {
 background: #f6f6f6;
 background-position: center center; 
 max-width: 80%;
 padding: 20px; // turn it into 20px
}

body{
 background-image: url(http://www.westonsnorwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/woodgrainlight.jpg);
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy and thorough answer! That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

**Add padding to your main container.** Your text is inside the `wrap` container and adding padding to the body push the `wrap` container but not overriding the padding to `wrap` container. If you add `padding: 50px;` to `body`, then you will notice that the `wrap` container is more pushed but not the content. If you want to push the content, then add padding to your `wrap` container.

```
.wrap{
   padding: 20px;
}
```

Note: You have already padding on your `.wrap` but you are missing `px` unit in it as pointed in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your leaving the unit prefix(px) of your values i.e.

```
.wrap {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

likewise on:

```
body{
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrap {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    background-position: center center; 
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;  <---------- You're missing the px unit
}
```